# Return value from asynchronous function and pass result to another function

Tags: javascript

I'm using a class to do do some database stuff. In this example I want to reset the data and return the data.

```
export default class Db {
  constructor () {
    this.connection = monk('localhost:27017/db')
  }

  async resetDB () {
    const Content = this.connection.get('content')
    await Content.remove({})
    await createContent()
    return Content.findOne({ title: 'article' })
  }
}
```

In my test I'm calling the `db.resetDB()`, but I need to get the returned value, as I need to pass the ID as parameter.
But how do I do that? I think my problem is, that this is asynchronous.

```
let id
describe('Test', () => {
  before(() => {
    db.resetDB(res => {
      id = res._id
      Article.open(id) // How do I get the ID?? I do get undefined here
      Article.title.waitForVisible()
    })
  })

  it('should do something', () => {
    // ...
  })
})
```

Comment: you pass a callback to `resetDB` in the test but you do not use it in the actual code? `resetDB` is an async function with no parameters in your code

Comment: The `resetDB` function you posted is an `async function` that does return a promise and does not take a callback?! Did you mean `db.resetDB().then(res => {…`?

Comment: You should use `await db.resetDB()`, just like calling any other async function.

Answer (score 1):

When the async function is called, it returns a Promise. hence you can get the return value in .then() of the promise. You can do it something like this,

```
let id
describe('Test', () => {
  before(() => {
    db.resetDB().then(res => {
      id = res._id
      Article.open(id) // How do I get the ID?? I do get undefined here
      Article.title.waitForVisible()
    })
  })

  it('should do something', () => {
    // ...
  })
})
```

Comment: you should probably return that promise chain, so that the `before` hook actually waits on it to resolve and the tests get data in proper order

Answer (score 0):

You can make the before function to wait until all asynch calls gets finished by using done() callback.

https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support

What you can do is

```
let id
describe('Test', () => {
  before((done) => {
    db.resetDB().then(res => {
      id = res._id
      Article.open(id) // How do I get the ID?? I do get undefined here
      Article.title.waitForVisible()
      done()
    })
  })

  it('should do something', () => {
    // ...
  })
})
```

Comment: I do get the error `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: done is not a function`

Comment: @user3142695 forget about the previous comment i can't edit it for some reason. But I think the problem is with before callback, it should be  beforeEach not before.